# convert image to base64 in expo react-native(only in the frontend): PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, base64, expo

I'm trying to convert the image to base64 in expo react-native app by using the next code:

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
......

const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

but I get this error:

```js
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (C:\Users\rapha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (C:\Users\rapha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
    at read (C:\Users\rapha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
....
    at Server.app (C:\Users\rapha\university\MA\third year\finalProject\argon-react-native-master\oneWay\node_modules\connect\index.js:51:37)
    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:790:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
```

I'm looking for a solution only in the frontend, in this step the app not using the backend.

how can I fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

I tried many solutions but nothing for me then I decided to resize the image to quality 0.5 and it work to me

```js
let result = await  ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes:await ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing:true,
    aspect:[4,3],
    quality:0.5

})

  ....       
const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

Comment: There is no readAsStringAsync function in expo-file-system

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not this line, it works properly. It is the fetch API or the server file size limit.